FragmentContainerView cause InflateException on Robolectric UnitTest
I am using Robolectric (4.12.2) on my android app UnitTest. It tests works fine but one test is failing due to an exception: InflateException: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView. The xml layout is like this:
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.sampleapp.MyFragment" />

Then I use the xml layout to Jetpack Compose's AndroidViewBinding:
@Composable
fun MyWebView() {
    AndroidViewBinding(
        factory = MyFragmentLayoutBinding::inflate,
        update = {
            // omitted codes
        }
    )
}

I tried searching but I can't find any solution. Tried ChatGPT and it says Robolectric not fully support FragmentContainerView and suggest to use FrameLayout instead.
Does anyone encounter this and able to resolve it? Should I really need to switch to FragmeLayout?
